# javascript how to add new object into object after it has been created

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

This is my object:

```
var example = {"119":{"bannerId":"119","overlay":"3","type":"1",...},"210":{"bannerId":"210","overlay":"3","type":"1",...},...}
```

In this way I can very easily access or modify object. For example if I want to add new property I simply call this:

```
example[119].newProperty = 1;
```

And very easily access it:

```
alert(example[119].newProperty)
alert(example[210].type)
```

By knowing banner id, I can access any data from any scope of code, this is the reason I chose this pattern. The problem is that I need to add new object inside `example` after it has been created. For example I need to push this into example:
{"30":{"bannerId":"119","overlay":"3","type":"1",...}}

And I don't know if this is possible. Is it? One way to solve this problem would be to use array, so example would be array and each key would carry object, and I could push into array new key with object. But I am not sure if this is proper way because key will start with 200, 300, ... console.log(example) shows undefined for all keys before 200. Is fine to have so many empty keys? Is any other better way?

EDIT:

I realized this can be done also with object. The problem was because I was trying to assign new property directly into new object like this:

```
example[200].example3 = 2;
```

guessing it is enough that example object is created. What I was missing is this line:

```
example[200] = {}
```

Thanks for answers, it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var example = {};

example["30"] = {"bannerId":"119","overlay":"3","type":"1"}

console.log(example);
```

If its inside a loop you can also try something like below.

```
var i = 0;
var example = {};
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
  example[i] = {bannerId : i+1 , someOtherItem : i + "Hello"}
}

console.log(example);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
example[30] = {"bannerId":"119","overlay":"3","type":"1",...};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always access (and assign) ad hoc keys of objects, even if you didn't define them in the first place.

So for your example you can just do:

```
example["30"] = {... /*your new object*/...}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to extend your object, you could use jQuery or underscore more or less like this:

```
$.extend(true, example, { "30": { objectId: "201" }}); // deep copy
```

If you don't want to use any library simply do:

```
example["30"] = myObj["30"];
```